# Derived object created without having default constructor

Tags: c++

I was doing a small test in a site and I run to this problem.

```
#include<iostream.h> 
class Base
{
    int x, y, z; 
    public: 
    Base()
    {
        x = y = z = 0;
    }
    Base(int xx, int yy = 'A', int zz = 'B')
    {
        x = xx;
        y = x + yy;
        z = x + y;
    }
    void Display(void)
    {
        cout<< x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
    int x, y; 
    public:
    Derived(int xx = 65, int yy = 66) : Base(xx, yy)
    {
        y = xx; 
        x = yy;
    }
    void Display(void)
    {
        cout<< x << " " << y << " ";
        Display(); 
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived objD;
    objD.Display();
    return 0; 
}
```

I choose the compile error choice because we are instantiating a Derived object with zero argument's for the constructor and we have defined one which takes 2 arguments. As far as I know if we define a constructor our self the compiler doesn't provide the default one any more. I run the code and it compiled correctly. Can someone please explain it made me really confused.

Comment: Your defined constructor has two arguments *with default values.* It can take two arguments, or one, or zero.

Comment: You should get in the habit of using the constructor initialization list in preference over the body. So for example `Base()
    {
        x = y = z = 0;
    }` becomes `Base() : x(0), y(0), z(0) 
    {
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you have default parameters in your c'tor meaning if you don't pass parameters in then it defaults the parameters. Your constructor can handle 0,1 or 2 parameters.

If you change:

```
Derived(int xx = 65, int yy = 66) : Base(xx, yy)
```

to

```
Derived(int xx, int yy) : Base(xx, yy)
```

then your compile will fail

**additionally**

Since your c'tor can be used with just one argument you probably want to do use `explicit`:

```
explicit Derived(int xx = 65, int yy = 66) : Base(xx, yy)
```

This disallows implicit conversion occuring when you don't expect them. Explicit conversion is still possible. If you remove the default values then you will not need to do this because your c'tor can then **only** take 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The `Derived` class doeasn't have a parameterless constructor, but it *has* a constructor which can be called without parameters: a call to `Derived::Derived()` gets resolved as `Derived::Derived(65, 66)` by default parameter values.

Comment: so a constructor which has all the parameters as default is the default constructor?

Comment: Yes. See [Default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) at cppreference.com: _'A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or with default arguments provided for every parameter)'._

Comment: @ArisKoutsoukis See _Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++_ [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/), specifically the part [11.4.4.1 Classes –  Default constructors, par. 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1).